# Force an Android app to run on its own CPU core

Tags: android, performance, cordova, cpu-cores

I'm want to improve the performance of a Phonegap-based Android app. As of today, the project build target is Android 4.3.

How can I force the Android OS to give my app its own core in the CPU (for example in a quad-core device)?

Comment: Thankfully this is not possible. Other apps want to have CPU as well. If you want to improve performance go native.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "Thankfully" ..

Cause there is only 1 app you can be in which is full screen.. so let's say you have 4 cores, you should give 1 core to the 1 program which is full screen... don't you agree ?

and with them there will be more cores ..

Comment: Ok, this was a bit harsh. Just thought your app wanted my app to be starved ;-) I'd really count on Android and modern browsers to utilize given cores the best way possible. Maybe you search for '3D hardware acceleration' options and 'translate3d' for HTML5/CSS3 to gain maximum performance. Sometimes it's better not using it - it's a complex thing...

Comment: I just want the guy who is working the hardest to get most of the food :) Thanks I'll try this translate3d thingy

Comment: The OS should always handle delegation of work to the CPU, never the apps. Imagine the abuse that could occur if apps could control their CPU time!

Comment: But Apps should be allowed to 'recommend' the OS to use more CPU time, for example if there's a real-time app ..... yet the OS should agree\not agree on that request ..... so the app won't get the CPU in 100% of the cases, only the ones the OS approved ....